# Display timer GLUT game

Tags: c++, opengl, timer, glut

How can I display a timer that keeps incrementing every 10 milliseconds. I already have a function X that calls `glutTimerFunc(10, X, 0);` and increments the value of the `timer` every time by `0.1` but the problem is in displaying the value of the timer itself in a certain position in the window. I tried using a method to print the values and call it in my `Display()` method which is in `glutDisplayFunc(Display)` but it's not working correctly for some reason. The code of the method is below.

```
void displayTimer(void * font, int z, float x, float y)
{
    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    glutBitmapCharacter(font, z);
}
```

Comment: "not working correctly" isn't a very good description of your problem. Does it display an unexpected value, or in the wrong position, or something else?

Comment: `glutBitmapCharacter`, as its name suggests, is not [supposed to write a number](https://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/glut/spec3/node76.html).

Answer (score 1):

According to the header of your displayTimer() function, it seems that you are trying to show a z coordinate on screen and not the actual timer you want.

First, I suggest renaming the 'z' parameter to 'text' and change its data type to std::string. You can then pass your timer value as a string to your displayTimer() function. Next, you will have to iterate through the 'text' string in order to display it (character-by-character) on screen.

Here's an example how your function would look like:

```
void displayTimer(void * font, std::string text, float x, float y)
{
    glRasterPos2f(x, y);
    for (string::iterator i = text.begin(); i != text.end(); ++i)
    {
      char c = *i;
      glutBitmapCharacter(font, c);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure how your code is structured but one example on how to use your X() function along with your Display() function to show a timer value on screen would be as follows:

```
#include <string>

std::string timerValue;
void * textFont;

void X(int value)
{
   timerValue = std::to_string(value);
}

void displayTimer(void * font, std::string text, float x, float y)
{
   glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f); // Set color to green purely for testing.
   glRasterPos2f(x, y);
   for (string::iterator i = text.begin(); i != text.end(); ++i)
   {
     char c = *i;
     glutBitmapCharacter(font, c);
   }
}

void Display()
{  
    displayTimer(textFont,timerValue,10.0f,20.0f);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

    timerValue = 0;
    textFont = = GLUT_BITMAP_HELVETICA_18;

    glutTimerFunc(10,X,0);
    glutDisplayFunc(Display);

    glutMainloop();

    return 0;
 }
```

Notice how **char** data is passed to the glutBitmapCharacter() function in the displayTimer() function instead of a z integer.

Tip: To avoid some compiler warnings, change the data type of your x and y displayTimer() function parameters to **GLfloat**, as this is the datatype used for the glRasterPos2f() function.